# MAX Query returns set results when using dbmail

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xml

I am setting up alerts in a system and I want to query a db table and get the max date passed in to a data row and only that one entry.

For some reason, when I do it, the HTML email that comes through has the same date *over and over* again.

How do I get it to where it stops repeating itself and just does the max date only?

```
SET @tableHTML16 =
    N'<H1>BDI Feeds Last Received Batch</H1>' +
    N'<table border="1">' +
    N'<tr><th>Cerner</th><th>CPACS</th><th>DSCH123</th>' +
    CAST  ((SELECT   td = (select max(CPProcessedDateTime) from eiwdata..eiwtcontentreceived (nolock) where CapturePointDesc='OneC_Cerner_BDI:OCBDI1'), '',
                     td = (select max(CPProcessedDateTime) from eiwdata..eiwtcontentreceived (nolock) where CapturePointDesc='OneC_CPACS_BDI:OCBDI1'), '',
                     td = (select max(CPProcessedDateTime) from eiwdata..eiwtcontentreceived (nolock) where CapturePointDesc='OneC_DSCH123_BDI:OCBDI1'), ''

            from eiwdata..eiwtcontentreceived (nolock)


        FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
    N'</table>' ;
```

You can see what it looks like when it gets to this portion of the script by looking in sysmail all items:

```html
<H1>BDI Feeds Last Received Batch</H1>
<table border="1">
<tr><th>Cerner</th><th>CPACS</th><th>DSCH123</th>
<tr><td>2018-02-28T17:28:13.450</td><td>2018-02-28T16:31:51.113</td><td>2018-02-28T16:55:35.433</td></tr>
<tr><td>2018-02-28T17:28:13.450</td><td>2018-02-28T16:31:51.113</td><td>2018-02-28T16:55:35.433</td></tr>
<tr><td>2018-02-28T17:28:13.450</td><td>2018-02-28T16:31:51.113</td><td>2018-02-28T16:55:35.433</td></tr>
<tr><td>2018-02-28T17:28:13.450</td><td>2018-02-28
```

I of course had to shorten it, but it just goes over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least one `from eiwdata..eiwtcontentreceived (nolock)` too many. You are fetching the max value for each row in `eiwdata..eiwtcontentreceived`.

```
SET @tableHTML16 =
    N'<H1>BDI Feeds Last Received Batch</H1>' +
    N'<table border="1">' +                          -- close </tr> here
    N'<tr><th>Cerner</th><th>CPACS</th><th>DSCH123</th></tr>' +
    CAST  ((SELECT   td = (select max(CPProcessedDateTime) from eiwdata..eiwtcontentreceived (nolock) where CapturePointDesc='OneC_Cerner_BDI:OCBDI1'), '',
                     td = (select max(CPProcessedDateTime) from eiwdata..eiwtcontentreceived (nolock) where CapturePointDesc='OneC_CPACS_BDI:OCBDI1'), '',
                     td = (select max(CPProcessedDateTime) from eiwdata..eiwtcontentreceived (nolock) where CapturePointDesc='OneC_DSCH123_BDI:OCBDI1'), ''

/*
             This table reference should be removed
             from eiwdata..eiwtcontentreceived (nolock)
*/    

        FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
    N'</table>' ;
```